# Antialias not working in ubuntu lucid lynx 10.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fonts, ubuntu-10.04, fontconfig

I have recently upgraded from karmic to lucid (plain ubuntu using gnome).

Everything worked fine, but the characters now aren't anti-aliased any more, as you can appreciate from the screenshot:

[image]

This is what I tried to fix the situation, unluckily without succeeding:

1. Used the regular option pane from System->Preference->Appearance->Font (smoothing, hinting...)
2. Edited the `.fonts.conf` file
3. Disinstalling (and then re-installing) the `mstcorefont` package
4. Changing the default `Sans` font to a font of my liking (e.g. `Tahoma`) from the abovementioned Appearance options

My ubuntu installation is quite standard, with the typical add-ons one might wish for usability. I used the [ubuntu start script](https://launchpad.net/ubuntustart) to make a few tweaks.

Comment: Can not confirm, everything is still antialiased nicely after upgrade. I'm using Bitstream Vera Sans though.

Comment: @vava - It seems it has something to do with the font. I am now using a non-standard font and it does antialias correctly, but as soon as I switch to "sans" (which I do not know where points at) or "tahoma" the antialiasing gets messy... Any suggestion on how to refine the search is welcome.

Comment: When you edited .fonts.conf, did you try setting autohint to true?

Comment: Did you try the system's `fonts.conf` or just the one in your user's home directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was never able to fix the problem with that release, but the new LTS 12.04 does not present the same problem any more.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a new user, log in as the new user, and see whether the problem still exists. If not, something's wrong with your configuration under $HOME (which is common after a distribution upgrade). If it still exists, something is wrong with the system. You may need to `sudo aptitude purge` some packages (and reinstall them after that, of course) instead of just `remove`, which leaves system-wide configuration files untouched.